# Build .NET 4.0 and 4.6 Framework app in Jenkins

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, msbuild

I have few C# projects which requires .net framework 4.0 msbuild.exe

`"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"` to build the project.

But now i have one c# project which requires .net framework 4.6 msbuild.exe.
So i installed following components:

```
•   Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6
•   Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack
•   Microsoft Build Tools 2015
```

pointed my msbuild to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"`.

But when i'm installing .net framework 4.6 it upgrades 4.0 so i'm facing issues while building .NET 4.0 Framework apps.

So is it possible to build 4.0 apps with 4.6 msbuild.exe?

Comment: Go to your project properties > Application. Then, change the target framework to what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But its not possible for me to change the target framework for every project.

Comment: Why? It's not a choice. If you want to build a 4.0 assembly you must target this framework in your project properties. With or without 4.6 installed.

Answer (score 0):

The .net framework can only have one installation on each PC for each major version - i.e. 4.*.

The different versions of msbuild are associated with the ms tools version.

The .net 4.6 is a drop in replacement for .net 4.0, so you cannot have both installed, they use the same directory.

You can configure a jenkins slave machine which has the .net 4.0 framework on it, and mark the builds which require .net 4.0 to run on it.

See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines

Comment: Thanks a lot. But is there an way i can build these apps (4.0 and 4.6) without creating a slave machine?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry

Comment: Thanks but just one question i have configured slave machine but now i want a specific job to build on that machine so how can i give the slave machines reference in a job? So that job will build on that machine.

Comment: In your slave machine configuration give it a label, e.g. "net40". Then in your job, tick "Restrict where this project can be run" and type net40 in the Label Expression text field.